# Schwefel function trying to find global minimum with three variables, but I am receiving a error from function

Tags: function, matlab, genetic

I am writing a Schwefel function with three variables `x1`, `x2` and `x3` with x (-400,400), I am trying to find the global minimum of a Schwefel function. Can anybody tell me what's wrong with the function code.

```
function output = objective_function(in)
x1 = in(1);
x2 = in(2);
x3 = in(3);
output=(-x1.*sin(sqrt(mod(x1)))+(-x2.*sin(sqrt(mod(x2)))+(-x3.*sin(sqrt(mod(x3)));
ouput=[F1 F2];
```

Comment: What's going wrong? How is the result not what you expect?

Comment: This is an *exact* copy of a question posted [on the MathWorks forum](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/683338-shewel-function-writing-to-find-the-global-minimum-with-three-variables).

Comment: As the Mathworks post suggests variables `F1` and `F2` have not been defined or initialized before being used.

Answer (score 0):

### Current Problems:

1: Mismatched delimiters in line:

```
output=(-x1.*sin(sqrt(mod(x1)))+(-x2.*sin(sqrt(mod(x2)))+(-x3.*sin(sqrt(mod(x3)));
```

---

2: Modulus requires a second argument. The second argument inputted into the `mod()` function needs to be the divisor. The modulus can only return the remainder if it knows the number being divided (dividend) and the number that is dividing (divisor). Calling the `mod()` function can follow the form:

```
mod(dividend,divisor);
```

***Aside:***

*`mod()` is often used accidentally in replace of `abs()`*

Modulus → `mod()` : Returns the remainder after division.
Example: `mod(10,3) = 1` → 10/3 = 3 with remainder 1

Absolute → `abs()`: Returns the absolute/magnitude of the number.
Example: `abs(-10) = 10`  or `abs(1 + 1i) = 1.4142`

---

3: Variables `F1` and `F2` are not defined or initialized before being used. The variable called `ouput` may be a typo.

```
ouput=[F1 F2];
```

---

### Playground Script:

Not sure what the function is supposed to exactly do but here is a script that you can modify to meet your needs. This gets rid of the errors but might need to be reconfigured to suit your exact functionality and output equation.

```
in = [1 2 3];
[output] = objective_function(in);

function [output] = objective_function(in)
x1 = in(1);
x2 = in(2);
x3 = in(3);

%Splitting into terms will help with debugging bracket balancing issues%
Divisor = 2;
Term_1 = (-x1.*sin(sqrt(mod(x1,Divisor))));
Term_2 = (-x2.*sin(sqrt(mod(x2,Divisor))));
Term_3 = (-x3.*sin(sqrt(mod(x3,Divisor))));

output = Term_1 + Term_2 + Term_3;

end
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**